# Flatten and restore a complex vector into a double vector and back

Tags: c++, vector, complex-numbers

I have a vector containing complex values (either defined as `std::vector<std::complex<double>>` or `arma::cx_vec`) and would like to convert them into vectors containing double-values of twice the size. Afterwards I would like to convert them back again. Currently I use two loops (here from going from double-vectors to complex vectors and back):

```
//get x and dx as vectors containing real values, with a size of 2 * dim
arma::cx_colvec local_x(dim), local_dx(dim);
for(size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); i += 2) {
    local_x(i / 2) = std::complex<double>(x(i), x(i + 1));
}
//Do something with local_x and local_dx
for(size_t i = 0; i < 2 * dim; i += 2) {
    dx(i) = local_dx(i / 2).real();
    dx(i + 1) = local_dx(i / 2).imag();
}
//Send dx back
```

I can imagine that that might be rather slow. Therefore, are there other possibilities of reshaping those vectors from complex to double and back? Ideally involving iterators (such that I can use methods such as `transform()`) instead of a loop over a size.

Background to this question is: I have complex input data which has to be put into a function `A` which I can not modify, but which calls a user-supplied function again (called `U`). This function does not support complex data types, only real types. Therefore, my intention was to flatten the vector before putting it into `A`, unflatten it in `U`, do the calculations on it, reflatten it and send it back again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::complex<double>` is [explicitly](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) called out as something that can be treated as a `double[2]`

> ### Array-oriented access
>
> For any object `z` of type `complex<T>`, `reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(z)[0]`
>   is the real part of `z` and `reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(z)[1]` is the
>   imaginary part of `z`.
>
> For any pointer to an element of an array of `complex<T>` named `p` and
>   any valid array index `i`, `reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)[2*i]` is the real part
>   of the complex number `p[i]`, and `reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)[2*i + 1]` is
>   the imaginary part of the complex number `p[i]`
>
> The intent of this requirement is to preserve binary compatibility
>   between the C++ library complex number types and the C language
>   complex number types (and arrays thereof), which have an identical
>   object representation requirement.

So you can use `std::vector::data()` to obtain a `complex<double> *`, and reinterpret it as a `double *` with twice as many elements.

Comment: That is very helpful. The second part of the question was asking how to convert double[2] back into complex<double>. Do you have any idea how to do this?
(Except the non-efficiant way of constructing each complex object like complex<double>(p[i][0], p[i][1])).
Thanks!